# angular 404 for files on refresh

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So I know this question gets asked a lot but I've got a weird one here, I have two angular projects both running version 6.1.1,

Project A doesn't have hash and I'm trying to get Project B to also not use hash in the URL, I've matched everything I can and both projects run using npm run start using a basic node server, however Project B keeps throwing 404 if I refresh the site when I've navigated down the route

e.g http://localhost:9876/category/books

On Project A I can refresh the page on subroutes and the asset files are still being requested from the root.

I've read all the post where you change web config or htaccess but I am just using ng serve to run both projects.  I can't track down what the difference between the two projects is that makes it work for A but not B.

The only thing left I can spot is that the apps.routing.ts in the working project A uses LoadChildren './views/users/users.module#UsersModule'

Project B uses a standard route

{
path: 'category/:catId/subcategory/:id/:name',
component: SubCategoryComponent,
data: {
title: 'Browse [name]'
}
}

I realise once deployed I could set the webconfig/htaccess but I just want it working during dev time using ng serve.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found it finally in the index.html file

for working Project
 for Project that was not working